# How to use SVG images in HTML in such a way as to allow download of PNG version?

Tags: html, svg, download, html-object

I have lots of `.svg` images like `foo23.svg`. I also have corresponding `foo23.png`. I'd like to use the SVG in my HTML for web browsing, but I'd like to have it so that when you right-click (or control-click) on the image, you have the option to download the PNG. Can this be done?

Currently I like using `<object data="foo23.svg">` to insert the image. Can the above be done still using `<object>`?

An extension of my question comes from also having `foo23.pdf` and `foo23.eps`. Can right-clicking lead to several download options?

Answer (score 3):

This is untested but the way I would approach this is:

HTML:

```
<img src="foo23.png" />
```

CSS (courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21421125/5158636):

```
img {
    background-image: url(foo23.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding: 35px 120px; // adjust that depend on your image size
}
```

That way the image that gets displayed should be the .svg file (won't work in all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css) but the file you get prompted to save should be the .png file.