# Want to fetch image using javascript from css url so I can style the background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Want to fetch an image using javascript from CSS URL  so I can style the background image with background-size: cover and colour. The code is used for simply Fast Image Loading With Javascript

```js
var image = document.images[0]
var bigImage = document.createElement("img")
   bigImage.onload = function () {
    image.src = this.src
}
setTimeout(function () {
    bigImage.src = "img/large.jpg";
}, 50)
```

```css
.header-image {
  padding: 200px 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-size: cover;  
  height: 75vh; 
}
```

```html
<img id="image" class="header-image" src="img/small.jpg" width="1200" />
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question. What do you mean by fetch? What is your desired result?

Comment: still not understanding... which CSS image? Your code doesn't show any CSS with image, url, linear-gradient... nothing like that. Edit your question, rebuild your way of asking because currently it's hard to get what you want

Comment: I think I understand your question. You just want to be able to adjust the placement of the image in the element more specifically than the standard `<img>` tag allows, so you're trying to adjust the `background` properties to do so.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear I want to get rid of  <img id="image" class="header-image" src="img/small.jpg" width="1200" /> then somehow get the imge from css url this way I can add style to the background image

Comment: Yes that what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

The `src` of the `<img>` is actually the foreground content of the `<img>` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700136/css-background-image-over-html-img#answer-18700191)). So, if you set the `background-image` of an `<img>` as well as the `src`, the `src` will just override the `background-image`.

In this case, I would recommend you just set the `background-image` of a `<div>`.

```js
var url = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51IwmuOPQyL._SL1052_.jpg";
var element = document.querySelector('.example');
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + url + ")";
```

```css
.example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```